# Is this function concave or can it be made concave?

Tags: statistics, optimization, convex-optimization

I am working with a point process with an event arrival rate of:

$$ \lambda(t) =  \mu +  \sum\limits_{t_i<t}{\alpha e^{-\beta(t-t_i)}}$$

where $ t_1,..t_n $ are the event arrival times.

The log likelihood function is therefore:

$$  - t_n \mu + \frac{\alpha}{\beta} \sum{( e^{-\beta(t_n-t_i)}-1 )} + \sum\limits_{i<j}{\ln(\mu+\alpha e^{-\beta(t_j-t_i)})} $$

To obtain the maximum likelihood estimate (MLE) I need to maximize this log likelihood function under the restrictions that $\mu, \alpha, \beta > 0$ and $\beta > \alpha$.

1. Is the log likelihood function concave? The parameters are  $\mu, \alpha, \beta$.
2. If not, is there a reparameterization that would make it concave?

In R code the log likelihood is

```
l.loglik <- function(params, data, opt=TRUE) {
  mu <- params[1]
  alpha <- params[2]
  beta <- params[3]
  t <- sort(data)
  r <- rep(0,length(t))
  for(i in 2:length(t)) {
    r[i] <- exp(-beta*(t[i]-t[i-1]))*(1+r[i-1])
  }
  loglik <- -tail(t,1)*mu
  loglik <- loglik+alpha/beta*sum(exp(-beta*(tail(t,1)-t))-1)
  loglik <- loglik+sum(log(mu+alpha*r))
  if(!opt) {
    return(list(negloglik=-loglik, mu=mu, alpha=alpha, beta=beta, t=t,
                r=r))
  }
  else {
    return(loglik)
  }
}
```

Comment: Alas, it is *convex* in the variables $t_i$, not concave. I think the transformation $s_i=e^{\beta t_i}$, $i=1,2,\dots, n-1$ will make it concave in $s_1,s_2,\dots,s_{n-1}$, but I'm not sure I see a way to make it concave in $t_n$.

Comment: @MichaelGrant I must have misunderstood but aren't the $t_i$ all just given as input and it is the variables $\mu, \alpha,\beta$ that we need to optimize over?  In other words, isn't the OP asking if the function is concave in $\mu, \alpha,\beta$?

Comment: Ah, good point, I did misread.

Comment: It is not clear for me how you derive loglikelihood function and with respect to what indexes you have summations there. Could you specify the original likelihood function? Do I understand right that your measurements are $t_i$ and you try to estimate parameters for distribution of $t-t_i$ ?

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner I added code which explicitly shows how to compute it. Does this help at all?  The measurements are $t_i$ and you are trying to estimate $\mu, \alpha, \beta$ which gives the maximum likelihood.

Comment: Well, clearly you asked a similar question on both SE's: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/113872/8960

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you fix $\beta$ as a constant, the function is jointly concave in $(\mu, \alpha)$. That is because $\log(\mu + \alpha c)$ is jointly concave in $(\mu, \alpha)$. So you could fix $\delta>0$ and consider $\beta \in \{\delta, 2\delta, 3\delta, \ldots, K\delta\}$ for some value $K>0$.  Then for each $k \in \{1, \ldots,K\}$ do:

---

(i) Fix $\beta = k\delta$ and solve the concave maximization over $(\mu, \alpha)$ subject to $0 < \alpha < \beta$ and $0<\mu$.  Let the resulting value be $s_k$.

(ii) If $k==1$ then define $s_{best} = s_1$, $\mu_{best} = \mu$, $\alpha_{best} = \alpha$, $\beta_{best} = k\delta$.

(iii) If $k>1$, then if $s_k>s_{max}$ define $s_{max}=s_k$, $\mu_{best} = \mu$, $\alpha_{best} = \alpha$, $\beta_{best} = k\delta$.

---

The resulting $s_{best},\mu_{best}, \alpha_{best}, \beta_{best}$ values are a good approximation to the optimal answer (depending on how small your discretization unit $\delta$ is, and assuming $K\delta$ is larger than the optimal value of $\beta$). Overall, assuming the concave maximization is easy, this turns the 3-dimensional search for the best $\alpha, \mu, \beta$ into a 1-dimensional search for the best $\beta$.

Comment: Thank you for this. So does the function have a horrible shape if you don't consider $\beta$ as a constant?

Comment: I don't know.  But if you fix $(\mu, \alpha)$, then it does not look concave in $\beta$.